# Promises not executing correctly

Tags: typescript, promise

Below is the typescript code that runs on application load. The idea is to execute getSheetList method and then run getBookmarkList and then populate the qlikAppList array.

If the qlikAppList array is empty at the end of it, the application is to return an error message "No sheets exist in any of the apps in stream."

On my local machine this works correctly most of the time, every once in a while it throws that error. This code was deployed to a server and the error message is thrown every time.

What is wrong here?

```
app.runGetAppList().then((appList: IMasterItem[]) => {
            let promiseArray: Promise<void>[] = [];
            _.each(appList, (appItem) => {
                let appInfo = { //few fields };
                promiseArray.push(qlik.getSheetList(appItem.id).then((sheetsInfo) => {
                    if (sheetsInfo.length > 0) {//populate appInfo}
                }).then(() => {
                    bookmarkSvc.getBookmarkList(appItem.id).then((bookmarksInfo) => {
                        if (bookmarksInfo.length > 0) {//populate appInfo}
                        this.qlikAppList.push(appInfo);
                    });
                }));
            });
            Promise.all(promiseArray).then(() => {
                this.initializeScreen(this.qlikAppList.length > 0 ? undefined : 
"No sheets exist in any of the apps in stream.");                    
            });

public getSheetList(appId): Promise<QlikSheetInfo[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        currentApp.qlikApp.getList("sheet", (sheetList) => {
            resolve(sheetList.qAppObjectList.qItems.map((qItem) => {
                return {
                    //some fields
                };
            }));
        });
    });
}

public getBookmarkList(appId): Promise<QlikBookmarkInfo[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        currentApp.qlikApp.getList("BookmarkList", (bookmarkList) => {
            resolve(bookmarkList.qBookmarkList.qItems.map((qItem) => {
                return {
                    //some fields
                };
            }));
        });
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: TypeScript does not have promises. So it can't be the case that "TypeScript promises [are] not executing correctly". Promises are part of the standard JS library. For more help in debugging your code, please provide a minimal example, with everything non-essential stripped out. No one here has time to look over nearly a hundred lines of your code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have pared down the code to make it a bit more concise.

Comment: you aren't waiting for `getBookmarkList` to complete

Comment: How do I wait for getBookmarkList to complete? Javascript noob :(

Comment: I'm used to await/async, but I think adding a return here: `return bookmarkSvc.getBookmarkList...` should work

Comment: @vu1p3n0x thank you for that. That has resolved the issue. If you can add the same comment as an answer I will accept it. :)
Also can you explain why that "return" statement had to be added?

Comment: Also any comment on why the error that I am getting doesnt happen in all my environments? I was getting the error sporadically on my local and consistently on a server where the app was deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*upgrading comments into an answer*

You aren't waiting for `getBookmarkList` to complete; you are launching it in your `.then()` but it returns immediately, resolving the promise.

You should return the promise from `getBookmarkList` to make the promise propagate.

As to your comment about why it would happen sporadically depending on the environment: *you are in race-condition territory*. If at least one were to complete `getSheetList` and `getBookmarkList` before they all did just `getSheetList` then it'd be able to add an item to `qlikAppList` before the check. Factors like cpu speed, network speed/latency, OS threading, and precisely how the promises are resolved would all affect the timing.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about why it is happening only in certain environments.